# Добавить вариант в зависимости от выбора пользователя (html:form:select)

Tags: javascript

У нас есть форма:

```
<form name="poisk" action="result.php" method="get">
Оплата за: <select name="za_chto">
<option value="все" checked="checked">Всё равно
</option><option value="вариант1">вариант1
</option><option value="вариант2">вариант2
</option><option value="вариант3">вариант3
</option><option value="вариант4">вариант4
</option></select>
<input type="submit" value="Поиск">
</form>
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы после клика из выпадающего списка по варианту, например, "вариант1" стала видимой бы форма выбора марки, если пользователь выбрал "вариант2", то стала бы видимой форма выбора цены и так далее. Т.е. уже пользователю было бы доступно несколько параметров, в зависимости от его первоначального выбора.

Или, например, если пользователь выбрал "вариант1", то его бы средиректило на страницу "a", если "вариант2", то на страницу "b".

Как такое осуществить?

Comment: По моему эт js. Нет?

Comment: Да, но как бы это сделать. Думаю с помощью onClick. Вот наработка:

<code><option value="авто" onClick="javascript: window.alert('test');" />test</a></code>

Но оно не работает.

Comment: Если сделать так чтоб отправляло по страницам прост value="1.html" А js сорри не изучаю)

Comment: Дело в том, что весь процесс должен происходить сразу после клика. Ну все равно спасибо за помощь.

Comment: С джаваскриптом всё получится. Поставьте код *появления* какой-то части формы в событие `onChange` в `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью selectedIndex.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectnew(){
if(cat.selectedIndex=='1'){ 
path = 'Выплаты: <select name="test"><option value="test1" checked="checked" />Всё равно</option><option value="test2">Были</option><option value="test3">Не было</option></select>';
}
tre.innerHTML = path;
}
</script>
```